# How can I properly loop through a simple 2D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I don't understand why I can't find any clear answer on this! Such a basic thing...

I have a normal 2D matrix, such as this one:

```
matrix = zeros(w, h);
```

Where `w, h ∈ Z+`, which means `w` and `h` are positive integers greater than zero.

I need to loop through the matrix and do something with it's element. For this task, we can assume `h=3`. Therefore, I tried this:

```
        test = zeros(w, 3);
        for i = 1:test
            point = test(:,i);
            [point(0), point(1), point(2)] = MY_CONVERSION(point(0), point(1),point(2));
            test(:,i) = point;
        end
```

The `MY_CONVERSION` is `varargin` function and for 3 parameters defined as:

```
function [rho, alpha, z] = MY_CONVERSION(r, alpha, epsilon)
```

Of course, in real code the `test` contains data, not just zeros. But this code alone could, for example, fill matrix with random numbers. But it doesn't work.

I also tried using three variables to store the column values:

```
        for i = 1:Xi
            [a,b,c] = Xi(:,i);
            [a,b,c] = mysph2cyl(a, b, c);
            rho(:,i) = a,b,c;
        end
```

Matlab marks it as incorrect syntax:

> An assignment statement makes an assignment to multiple values, but
>   the expression on the right side of the assignment does not appear to
>   produce multiple values.

Comment: I updated the question, thank you. [Here's full code](http://pastebin.com/6X19ba9F). I didn't want to make the question unnecesarily long.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first piece of code is what you need to get it working.  However, your `for` loop is incorrect.  You probably want to iterative over all of the **columns**, so do `for i = 1 : size(test,2)`, not `test`. `size(test,2)` determines how many columns your matrix has.

Therefore:

```
    test = zeros(w, 3);
    for i = 1:size(test,2) %// Change here
        point = test(:,i);
        [point(0), point(1), point(2)] = MY_CONVERSION(point(0), point(1),point(2));
        test(:,i) = point;
    end
```

---

Also, your second piece of code, you need to fix that `for` loop problem like I mentioned above.  The first statement inside the `for` loop is superfluous.  You don't need it.  The third line of code needs to have `[]` surrounding `a,b,c`.

Comment: My function is defined as `function [a,b,c] =  MY_CONVERSION(varargin)`. Is this returning vector of 3 values or 3 values alone?

Comment: It will return the three values alone.  I took a look at your code, so we're fine.  I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, `matrix = zeros(w, h);` creates confusion: you are probably thinking of w as width and h as height. But the first argument of `zeros` is height: for example, `zeros(2,3)` is

```
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
```

Generally: row index first, column index second.

Then you have `for i = 1:test` but test is a matrix. You need a number here.

Here is a working example similar to your first fragment:

```
w = 2; h =3;        
test = zeros(w, h);
for i = 1:h
    point = test(:,i);
    point = cos(point)*i;  % sample conversion
    test(:,i) = point;
end
```

Output:

```
1     2     3
1     2     3
```